# Bookdown: Single html output file

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, bookdown

If I add a line below the first in `_output.yml`:

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  split_by: none
  css: ...
```

in the [bookdown-demo](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo) the output becomes a single `.html` file which looks kind of plain ugly. Is it somehow possible to retain the nice style which is produced by the default settings but in a single file? If I want to send the book to someone else sending a stack of files is not great, especially if the person who receives it is not familiar with HTML as a document format.

Comment: Sounds like a bookdown bug to me. I'll investigate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This turns out to be a bug of **bookdown**, and I just [fixed it](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/commit/cec8e8a44f50ccf5d98e1e8fb88f9d779549ad00) on Github. You can install and test the development version (>= 0.3.3):

```
devtools::install_github('rstudio/bookdown')
```